# Keras model shape incompatible / ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 3, 3) are incompatible

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, reshape, tf.keras

I'm trying to train my keras model but shapes are incompatible.
The error says

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 3, 3) are incompatible
```

My train set's shape is (2000, 3, 768) and lable's shape is (2000, 3).

What is the wrong the point?

Model define & fit code

```
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
model = my_dnn(input_shape, 3)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, verbose=1)
```

Model code

```
def my_dnn(input, num_classes):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(input))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(225))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


    model.compile( loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                   optimizer='adam', 
                   metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    return model
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `softmax` but not `sigmoid`?

Comment: Is yours a multilabel or multiclass problem? is your y one-hot encoded?

Comment: You cannot use `SparseCategoricalAccuracy()` but need `CategoricalAccuracy()` if you have OneHot encoded labels (shape (batch,3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what's said, it seems you are carrying the second dimension of the input data until the end of the model. So your model summary is something like this:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3, 1024)           787456    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 3, 1024)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 1024)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3, 512)            524800    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 3, 512)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3, 225)            115425    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 3, 225)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3, 100)            22600     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 3, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 3, 3)              303       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 3, 3)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,450,584
Trainable params: 1,450,584
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As you can see, the output shape of the model `(None, 3, 3)` is not compatible with the label's shape `(None, 3)`, and at some point, you need to use a `Flatten` layer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1. Your problem is multi-class classification, hence you need `softmax` instead of `sigmoid` + `accuracy` or `CategoricalAccuracy()` as a metric.
2. Your problem is multi-label classification, hence you need `binary_crossentropy` and `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()`

Depending on how your dataset is built/the task you are trying to solve, you need to opt for one of those.

For case 1, ensure your data is OHE(one-hot encoded).

Also, Marco Cerliani and Amir (in the comment below) point out that the data output needs to be in a 2D format rather than 3D : you should either preprocess the data accordingly before feeding it to the network or use, as suggested in the comment below, a `Flatten()` at a point (probably before the final `Dense()`)

Comment: this is correct... also the network is wrong... the output is 2D while the network is producing 3D